# ie9 webfonts not loading

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9, font-face, webfonts

I've tried all the other solutions provided here and elsewhere and I'm still having issues with webfonts loading in ie9.

Implemented the fix to the .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Not receiving any css3 error messages in ie developer console.

Thing is when the initial page loads, the fonts don't load but when I navigate to any other page on the site, the fonts then load.  If I go back to the initial page the fonts will now load too.

Feel like I've tried everything I was able to find on the web.

Heres my css:

```
/** FONTS **/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'UniversUltraCondensedRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/univers-ultracondensed-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/univers-ultracondensed-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/univers-ultracondensed-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/univers-ultracondensed-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('../fonts/univers-ultracondensed-webfont.svg#UniversUltraCondensedRegular') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
    }


@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-  opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('../fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
    }
```

[**Here's**](http://lisicreations.com/) the link to the site!

Thanks

Comment: There are security issues with `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`. Make sure you understand the risks before using that.

Answer (score 0):

TRY USING AN ABSOLUTE URL

```
@font-face { font-family: 'UniversUltraCondensedRegular'; src: url('../fonts/univers-ultracondensed-webfont.eot');
```

becomes

```
@font-face { font-family: 'UniversUltraCondensedRegular'; src: url('http://www.yourdomain.com/fonts/univers-ultracondensed-webfont.eot');
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the CSS you provided should work. Most likely, your problem is caused either by using the wrong paths or by having the wrong file permissions for your font files.

### How to tackle this issue :

First, test whether everything works correctly if you use absolute paths (as [**zaba**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2772310/zaba) suggested).

- If that does work, it means your paths are incorrect. In that case, make sure the path is **relative to the CSS file that contains the `@font-face` statement.**
- If that doesn't work, then your issue is probably not related to the `pathname`. In that case, check whether the file permissions are OK for your font files and the folder it's in.